# The add(elem) method changes every element in my array to elem?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, addition, combinations

I have the following code in my class:

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> allCombos;

public static void main(String[] args){
    allCombos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] arr = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    combinations(arr, 3, 0, new String[3]);

}

static void combinations(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result){
    if (len == 0){
        allCombos.add(result);   // this is where the problem seems to be
        return;
    }      
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
        combinations(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
    }
}
```

For some reason, each time `allCombos.add(result)` is called in `combinations()`, the method seems to set every single element in the whole array to the current value of result, thereby over-riding what the previous iteration of `combinations()` had set the most recently added value of `allCombos` as. The same thing happens if `allCombos` is a `Vector`.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: you´re only working with one instance of `String[]`, hence resulting in this instance beeing multiple times in the `List`, while only this `String[]` gets modified multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add the same `result` array to your `ArrayList` multiple times, so your `ArrayList` contains multiple reference to the same array object.

You should create a copy of the array in order for your `ArrayList` to contain distinct arrays.

Change

```
allCombos.add(result);
```

to

```
allCombos.add(Arrays.copyOf(result,result.length));
```

After making that change, printing your `allCombos` `List` gives :

```
[A, B, C]
[A, B, D]
[A, B, E]
[A, B, F]
[A, C, D]
[A, C, E]
[A, C, F]
[A, D, E]
[A, D, F]
[A, E, F]
[B, C, D]
[B, C, E]
[B, C, F]
[B, D, E]
[B, D, F]
[B, E, F]
[C, D, E]
[C, D, F]
[C, E, F]
[D, E, F]
```